# Repository Injection not been recognized as bean

Tags: java, spring

Hy everybody

I have this simplified version of my trouble. I´m trying to run my application but it fails as Repository is not beign recognized to be injected. I already tried to annotate Repository as Service and to add the repository package to be scanned, but none works. Can someone help me?

I get an exception

Description:

Field topicRepository in br.com.alura.controller.TopicController required a bean of type 'br.com.alura.repository.TopicRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.com.alura.repository.TopicRepository' in your configuration.

```
Controller/Service

@Autowired
private TopicRepository topicRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/api/topics", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Page<TopicBriefOutputDto> listTopics(TopicSearchInputDto topicSearch, @PageableDefault(sort="creationInstant", direction=Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageRequest) {
    Specification<Topic> topicSearchSpecification = topicSearch.build();
    Page<Topic> topics = this.topicRepository.findAll(topicSearchSpecification, pageRequest);
    return TopicBriefOutputDto.listFromTopics(topics);
}

Start

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"br.com.alura.controller"})
@EntityScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class ForumApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ForumApplication.class, args);
}

}

Repository

public interface TopicRepository extends Repository<Topic, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Topic> {

}
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly add ComponentScan annotation. SpringBootApplication annotation does the job for you. Just add basePackages = {"br.com.alura"}

Answer (score 0):

Probably You set incorrect `base package`. The package scope is too narrow.

Try this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"br.com.alura.repository"})
```

or change `br.com.alura.controller` to `br.com.alura`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"br.com.alura"})
```

Comment: I got a new exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'topicController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'topicRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'topicRepository' defined in br.com.alura.repository.TopicRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ForumApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class br.com.alura.model.Topic

Comment: Topic is annotated with @Entity

Comment: What did You do exactly? another option which You can try is `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.com.alura")`

Comment: I tried both alone and also togheter. but if you see there, the exception now was with the entity, that is in another package

Comment: add `@EntityScan(basePackages = "br.com.alura.model")`